# Riemann–Schwarz symmetry principle and confomal maps

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question regarding the application of the Riemann-Schwarz symmetry principle to conformal maps.
Suppose that a function $f(z)$ is holomorphic on a domain $\mathscr{D}$ and is continuous in  $\mathscr{D}$ including a curve $\gamma$. Where $\text{Im} f(z) = 0 $ for $z\in \gamma$. Then the function can be analytically continued to the domain $\mathscr{D}_0 = \mathscr{D} \cup \gamma \cup \mathscr{D}^{*}$

$$
F(z)=\begin{cases}
f(z) , z \in \mathscr{D} \cup \gamma \\ 
\overline{f(\overline{z})}, z \in \mathscr{D}^{*} \\
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$

What bothers me is how the analytically continued function $\overline{f(\overline{z})}, z \in \mathscr{D}^{*}$ looks like in practice.

Let's try a real world example. Suppose that we would like to map $\mathscr{D}_0$ being the complex plane with a cut along the lines $[-3i,3i]$ and $[-4,\infty]$ to the upper half plane.
We can't use $f(z)=z^2$ since it is not single valued on $\mathscr{D}_0$ (e.g. $(10i)^2=(-10i)^2$).
Therefore,  consider the part of $\mathscr{D}_0$, call it $\mathscr{D}_2$ where $\text{Im}z>0$ with a cut along $[0,3i]$.  Here $z^2$ is singe valued and using $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2+9}$ and maps $\mathscr{D}_2$ to the upper half plane. Where the branch $f(-4)=-5$ was chosen.

[image]

The question is how do we apply the R-S symmetry principle to map the entire $\mathscr{D}_0$ to the upper half plane.

Our function  $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2+9}$ takes real values on the real axis and the symmetry principle holds. However, how does the analytic continuation for the region $\mathscr{D}^{*}$ i.e. $\text{Im}z<0$ and cut along $[0,-3i]$ looks like?

In my book the answer is $\sqrt{5+\sqrt{z^2+9}}$. No complex conjugation, as indicated by (1), but why? Shouldn't that be $\overline{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{\overline{z}^2+9}}}$.
[image]